# PostgreSQL full text search cannot find "andy"

Tags: postgresql, search, full-text-search

I have this PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT d.user_id, display_name, avatar_url
FROM user_directory_search
WHERE
user_id like '@and%';
```

I get these results:

```
                    user_id             | display_name | avatar_url
----------------------------------------+--------------+------------
 @andy.huang:synapse.siliconmotion.com  |              |
 @andy.zhao:synapse.siliconmotion.com   | Andy.zhao    |
 @andy.yao:synapse.siliconmotion.com    |              |
 @andy.zou:synapse.siliconmotion.com    |              |
 @andy.xie:synapse.siliconmotion.com    |              |
 @andy.chang:synapse.siliconmotion.com  | andy.chang   |
 @andy.chuang:synapse.siliconmotion.com | andy.chuang  |
 @andy.hsiao:synapse.siliconmotion.com  |              |
(8 rows)
```

But when I use the command:

```
SELECT d.user_id, display_name, avatar_url
FROM user_directory_search
WHERE
vector @@ to_tsquery('english', '(andy:* | andy)');
```

I got nothing:

```
 user_id | display_name | avatar_url
---------+--------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the full text parser parses these strings as host names:

```
SELECT alias, description, token, lexemes
FROM ts_debug('english', '@andy.huang:synapse.siliconmotion.com')
WHERE alias <> 'blank';

 alias | description |           token           |           lexemes           
-------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------
 host  | Host        | andy.huang                | {andy.huang}
 host  | Host        | synapse.siliconmotion.com | {synapse.siliconmotion.com}
(2 rows)
```

You could replace the offending periods with spaces during indexing:

```
SELECT alias, description, token, lexemes
FROM ts_debug('english',
              translate('@andy.huang:synapse.siliconmotion.com', '.', ' '))
WHERE alias <> 'blank';

   alias   |   description   |     token     |   lexemes    
-----------+-----------------+---------------+--------------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | andy          | {andi}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | huang         | {huang}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | synapse       | {synaps}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | siliconmotion | {siliconmot}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | com           | {com}
(5 rows)
```

But I would use the `simple` full text search configuration if I were you. Or do you want stemming (compare "token" and "lexemes" above)?

Comment: I have no right to modify the source code, but I can update database. Do you know how to fix the database to solve the problem?

Comment: Another question is the problem is only occurred in 'andy' , others words like eric, bell, Akira... are all fine. Why 'andy' only?

Comment: You have to change the query to solve the problem, if only by introducing a new, modified column. `andy` is probably special because the English stemmer changes it to `andi`.